# Unexpected output when printing element of array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating a simple c program and output  of below program should be 2 but i am getting 50 dont know why (i am newbie to c) please let me know where i am missing

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   int a[4]={'1','2','2','\0'};
   printf("The value of a is %d",a[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

[here is live output](http://codepad.org/GflPS2mo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You initialised the array using [ascii character codes](http://www.asciitable.com/).  `'2'` has integer value 50.

Initialise the array as

```
int a[4]={1,2,2,0};
```

if you want it to contain integers 1,2,2,0.  Or

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   char a[4]="121";
   printf("The value of a is %c",a[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

if you want an array of characters that can be treated as a string.  (Note the use of the `%c` format specifier here.)

Comment: could you please answer some of my question regrading this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21757/loungec11?highlights=true here

Comment: Obviously, this "works" in any language. E.g. in java `System.out.println((int) '2');` prints `50`.

Answer (score 3):

`50` is the ASCII code of `'2'`.

Replace `'2'` with `2` if you want it fixed.

When using character literals like `'2'` C actually thinks of them as integer types. When you print it using `%d` format specifier you're telling C to print the value as integer.

If you want to keep the array elements like this: `'2'`, you'll need to change printf format to `%c` to get a `2` in the console.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Unfortunately, I can't remove my downvote unless you edit the question now

Comment: I don't care about your downvote dude. This site is for good info not for rep :)

Answer (score 3):

When you wrote `int a[4]={'1','2','2','\0'};` you actually initialized the array with ASCII Codes of the numbers 1 and 2.
This is because you enclosed them within single quotes thus making them characters instead of integers.
Hence the array actually takes the values `int a[4]={49,50,50,0};`
To rectify it, you should write the integers without the quotes:

```
int a[4]={1,2,2,0};
```

Also note that integer arrays don't need to end with `'\0'`. That is only for character arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
int a[4]={'1','2','2','\0'};
```

tells the compiler to create an integer array of length 4 and put into it the integers from the curled braces from the right.

Characters in `C` are 1-byte integers, `1` is a character of `1` and it means integer value of it's ASCII code, i.e. 50. So the first element of an array gets the value of 50.

To fix you should write

```
int a[4]={1,2,2,0};
```

remember, that `0` cannot serve as an array end marker, since it is just a number.

If you suppose to get `122` output then do

```
char a[4]={'1','2','2','\0'};
printf("The value of a is %s",a);
```

since strings in `C` are character arrays with `0` as termination symbol.

Also you can let compiler to count values for you

```
char a[]={'1','2','2','\0'};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning chars not integers:

note

```
'2' means char       use %c
 2  manes int        use %d
"2" means string.    use %s
```

all are different:

in your code you can do like to print 2:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   char a[4]={'1','2','2','\0'};
   printf("The value of a is %c",a[1]);
   return 0;
}
```